# NonStringExceptions consume considerable time when concatenation of hashes occurs

Tags: java, performance, exception, optimization, freemarker

We have a lot of FTL code that performs hash concatenation like this:

```
<#local event_data = event_data + {
   'subaction_name': subactionName
} />
```

However, these constructs cause some overhead due to the following code (the freemarker.core.AddConcatExpression class’ _getAsTemplateModel(Environment env) method):

```
try {
   String s1 = getStringValue(leftModel, left, env);
   if(s1 == null) s1 = "null";
   String s2 = getStringValue(rightModel, right, env);
   if(s2 == null) s2 = "null";
   return new SimpleScalar(s1.concat(s2));
} catch (NonStringException e) {
   if (leftModel instanceof TemplateHashModel && rightModel instanceof TemplateHashModel) {
       if (leftModel instanceof TemplateHashModelEx && rightModel instanceof TemplateHashModelEx) {
           TemplateHashModelEx leftModelEx = (TemplateHashModelEx)leftModel;
           TemplateHashModelEx rightModelEx = (TemplateHashModelEx)rightModel;
           if (leftModelEx.size() == 0) {
               return rightModelEx;
           } else if (rightModelEx.size() == 0) {
               return leftModelEx;
           } else {
               return new ConcatenatedHashEx(leftModelEx, rightModelEx);
           }
       } else {
           return new ConcatenatedHash((TemplateHashModel)leftModel,
                                       (TemplateHashModel)rightModel);
       }
   } else {
       throw e;
   }
}
```

because the getStringValue method throws NonStringExceptions in such cases. The NonStringException, in its turn, inherits the following constructor logic from the TemplateException:

```
super(getDescription(description, cause));
causeException = cause;
this.env = env;
if(env != null)
{
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
   env.outputInstructionStack(pw);
   pw.flush();
   ftlInstructionStack = sw.toString();
}
else
{
   ftlInstructionStack = "";
}
```

which fetches a full instruction stack each time regardless further handling.

This leads to up to 50 ms of execution time spent on the exception constructors per page request in our case, which is quite critical for the overall throughput.

Could anyone give some advices on how to avoid these exceptions without touching the FTL code, please? Or, maybe, it’s possible to get some kind of a patch, which would move the TemplateModelHash instanceof check before the catch block in the AddConcatExpression._getAsTemplateModel method?

**EDIT:**
freemarker version 2.3.19

Comment: My first question would be why this logic is being handled in the view layer in the first place--could you move it out to Java code? In general, handling logic in the view layer isn't a great idea, even less of a great idea when it's being handled by a scripting language that defines its own operations.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I agree that presentation layer should contain minimum logic. But, unfortunately, we can't rework presentation layer as there are tons of ftl. So, the only thing we can do is try to figure cause of this issue.

Comment: Could you do it some other way other than map concatenation?

Comment: Nope, there are too many ftls to apply these changes to all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the latest stable FreeMarker release (2.3.25 at the moment), and see if the speed will be acceptable. A commit in 2013-06-13 says:

> This reduces TemplateException creation resource usage further (as far
>   as it will be silently handled), as the final message from the blamed
>   expression, tips and so on is only assembled when the message is
>   indeed needed.

2.3.19 was released earlier than that, on 2012-02-29.

**Update:** I have committed into 2.3.26-nightly so that falling back to hash addition doesn't rely on exception throwing/catching at all. Not sure how dominant this was in your performance problem, but it was inefficient for sure.

Comment: With 2.3.19 we had 271ms as average response time. With 2.3.25 - 284ms. So, after version update, we can even see a little performance degradation. At least it didn't improve it.

Comment: So I guess then the time wasn't spent by constructing that message after all. Does the profiler still point at the exception construction? Throwing a new(!) exception is relatively expensive, as it has to capture the Java stack trace and such, even if you do nothing in the constructor.

Comment: How many concatenations per request is that BTW? I can do about 150000 concatenations per 250 ms on a single 3.3 GHz Haswell core. Not great, but are you really doing that much concatenation?

Comment: See update... until 2.3.26 is out (which I guess will take at least a month), you can build from the 2.3 or 2.3-gae brach of the Apache Github mirror. It has seeded up a very hash-addition-intensive test template 8.5 times, but that's a quite outlandish template of course.

Comment: After we applied updated version of freemarker we could reduce rendering time on about 34% percents! (217ms -> 144ms). I really appreciate your help!